# Should "request-after-request" be hyphenated?

Tags: hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

> "All day I get request-after-request for help on passing the Quality Assessment."

The sentence above was originally written as, "All day I get request after request for help on passing the Quality Assessment."

I changed "request after request" to "request-after-request," but was told that I was wrong.

Is request-after-request correct?

Comment: Google Ngram says [*Ngrams not found: request-after-request*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=request-after-request&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=).

Comment: I wouldn't hyphenate it.

Comment: No need to hyphenate in that setting, and we can appreciate the request-after-request irritation. The three words take the place of 'serial requests' and no more.  I might add 'long', as in All day long.

Comment: Hyphenation makes sense when *request after request* is used as an adjective, as in Yosef Baskin's comment, where it is used for clarity to modify *irritation*. Otherwise hyphenation is incorrect.

Comment: request-after-request makes a negative thing into a real concept.

Comment: If not acting as an adjective, what would we consider "request after request" as part of the construction of the sentence?

Comment: ... What would you consider _a series of requests_' role to be, if that noun phrase were substituted?

Comment: Edwin, ah, okay, so it's a noun phrase. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, hyphenation is definitely wrong in that context. Hyphenation is used only when the word becomes attributive.