# Hyphenation, adjectives and 'attributive' words

Tags: hyphenation

While explaining an answer on hyphenation, [(This was the question)](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/403170/244042)

I had a bit of trouble explaining where hyphenation should be used and where it should not.

For example, consider the following two sentences:

- His entry was *less than impressive*.
- His *less-than-impressive* entry let down the audience.

I know instinctively that the second sentence must use hyphenation, but am unable to explain why this is so. I've heard that the word in the second sentence is **attributive**, but I'm not sure what that means.

**Could somebody give a thorough explanation on when to use hyphenation in adjectives and when not to?**

Other such examples are: *know-it-all, devil-may-care, holier-than-thou, America-first, cloak-and-dagger, fairy-tale, drug-induced, kill-time,* and many, many more(which I don't seem to recall now)!

Comment: The Chicago Manual of Style (and it is a style question) has nine pages on hyphenation, which is often a matter of clarity and judgment.  Chicago follows Webster, and recommends consulting a dictionary as a first source.

Comment: Harry, huge numbers of people think adjectival hyphenation is so difficult, they'd rather it didn't exist, or had a *simpler* name.

In fact, if you string together a bunch of words and use them to describe whatever follows then the strung-together words need hyphens to do that stringing.

Yours are above-posted examples are excellent.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Thanks, could you develop on that and give an answer? I've never had to wait so long for an answer on Stack Exchange!

Comment: Yes but what with Google, Xanne's and my comments, what remains, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I guess nothing much remains! Thanks!!